# Using Numpy with ARM processors

Tags: python, numpy, arm

I'm trying to put numpy on a system with an ARM processor. I don't have much experience with these processors, so I'm not entirely sure where to start. I've tryed searching for an answer via google, but haven't had success on finding specifics about cross compiling numpy. I currently have python version 2.4 on the machine and am trying to import numpy 1.6.2 . Any suggestions on where I can look to start?

Comment: To clarify a little, I'm using armv5tejl architecture and MontaVista 3.4.3 for linux

Comment: It is 99% likely that your system does not have floating-point unit, so numpy will be too slow for practical use.

Comment: trivia: this is the 2000th arm tagged question.

Comment: more and more arms do have floating point even microcontrollers.  the processor in question, probably not.

Comment: did you try compiling numpy yet?

Comment: I still haven't tried compiling it. I'm still unsure about where to start...